# xfce terminal: run script on session restore

Tags: bash, xubuntu, xfce4-terminal

I'm quite happy with Xfce Terminal and how it restores my windows and tabs when I log in and how it even remembers the cwd for each tab.

For Python development, I've added a bash function to activate a virtual environment when I `cd` into a directory that has a virtual environment subdirectory. From my `.bashrc`:

```bsh
# Automatically en/dis-able Python virtual environments:
function cd() {
    builtin cd "$@"
    set_python_env
}
```

Unfortunately that code does not get called when the Xfce Terminal restores the session.

How can I run code when the session gets restored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't thinking... I can just call my `set_python_env` function at the end of `.bashrc` --- it's a no-op if called outside a directory with a Python virtual environment. Each new terminal tab has a shell running anyway.